# 'AddExerciseCommand' property not found on project

Tags: android, xaml

Im trying to use a command in the view and the output says
'AddExerciseCommand' property not found on 'Muscles_app.Models.ExerciseTypeGroup', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Command' How do I fix it?
Why is it not found. I have a working command in the class so it cant be missing some connection between the view and the viewmodel

```
public ICommand AddExerciseCommand => new Command(AddExercise);
 private void AddExercise()
 {
     if (SelectedGroup == null)
     {
         // Handle the case where no group is selected
         return;
     }

     // Example: Adding a new exercise to the selected ExerciseTypeGroup
     var newExercise = new Exercise
     {
         Reps = 0, // Set default values or initialize as needed
         Weight = 0
     };

     // Add the new exercise to the group
     SelectedGroup.ExercisesInGroup.Add(newExercise);

     // Dynamically add a new row to the grid
     AddGridRow();

     // You may want to update other properties or trigger events as needed
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ExerciseTypeGroups));
 }
```

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ExerciseTypeGroups}" HasUnevenRows="True">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <!-- Display ExerciseType of the group -->
                 <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0">
                     <Label Text="{Binding ExerciseType.Name}" FontSize="25" Padding="10" />
                     <Grid x:Name="ExerciseGrid">
                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                         <!-- Entry for Reps -->
                         <Entry Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Reps" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding Reps}" />

                         <!-- Entry for Volume -->
                         <Entry Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Volume" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding Weight}" />

                         <!-- Button to add exercise to the group -->
                         <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Complete" Command="{Binding CompleteExerciseCommand}" />
                         
                     </Grid>
                     <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Add Exercise" Command="{Binding AddExerciseCommand}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                 </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```